# How does my Telegram bot keeps running after encountering a Runtime Error?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

### Normal Script

Let's say we're writing a basic python program.

```
numbers = [1,2,3]
special_number = numbers[3]

print(special_number)
```

This code doesn't work, because it gives index out range error due to there are only 3 indexes not 4. Program will stop and won't work if we do not rerun it.

### Telegram Bot Script

However when we are creating a Telegram bot, this situation doesn't happen.

```
def foo(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    numbers = [1,2,3]
    special_number = numbers[3]

    print(special_number)
```

When the program runs the foo function, it gives error but doesn't stop. If it's a job that is repeated in every 10 minutes, Scheduler always call that function and gives error. Also, users can somehow trigger the function too. I'm curious about what is the reason behind this.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a try/except statement. Check out the python docs on [Errors and Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

```py
def f():
    ["a", "b", "c"][3] # this will error

try:
    f() 
    # The error will propagate up through function calls until it reaches
    # a try/except block (or there are no more functions, in which case your
    # program will stop and report the error as usual)
except IndexError as err:
    # This code will run if an IndexError happens. err will be a variable
    # with info on the error. Other errors will not be caught.
    print(err)
else:
    # This code will run only if there is no errors in the try: block.
    print("No errors!")
finally:
    # this code will run always at the end, no matter if an error occurred.
    print("Running finally block regardless")
```

Comment: Actually no, I know try-catch and I know how to solve the problem in Normal Script. The question I'm asking is how is this happening in while writing Telegram Bot Script even tho I don't use try-catch.

Comment: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/92cb6f3ae8d5c3e49b9019a9348d4408135ffc95/telegram/ext/dispatcher.py#L546 you can see the try/catch that they are using here. That calls the dispatcher, which calls your code. There's some additional complexities because of threading, but you can take a look and find it all there.